# Sed with regular expression and fixed part

Tags: sed, replace

I have a file with

```
<vcell i="2" v="2" s="0" m="0"/>
<cell i="3" v="3187"/>
<cell i="4" v="1"/>
<cell i="5" v="17"/>
<cell i="6" v="0"/>
<cell i="7" v="2"/>
<cell i="8" v="17"/>
<cell i="9" v="0 / 13"/>
```

I need to replace in

```
<vcelli2 v="2" s="0" m="0"/>
<celli3 v="3187"/>
<celli4 v="1"/>
<celli5 v="17"/>
<celli6 v="0"/>
<celli7 v="2"/>
<celli8 v="17"/>
<celli9 v="0 / 13"/>
```

I can do this with a sed and regular expression?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done with a sed command.

**Remember to backup the file before making any changes to it.** The backup can be removed after confirming that the results are correct or kept for later.

As for the `sed` command, something like

```
sed -i.backup -E 's/ i="([0-9]*)"/i\1/g' file
```

should work (note that this will automatically make a backup of the original file, remove the `backup` part if done manually).

The `-i` flag (not available in all flavours of `sed`) stands for in-place (i.e. save back to the original file; keep copy of original with extension `.backup`) and `-E` (extended regex) is used to avoid escaping the parentheses.

Comment: Not all portability issues have been resolved. There is simply no portable way to give an empty value to `-i` that works in all seds. The alternative that you propose will leave an additional file in the directory. The **only** truly portable solution for a *no additional file left* is a two step tango: `sed -E 's/ i="([0-9]*)"/i\1/g' file >newfile; mv newfile file` @Philippos

Comment: @Isaac Well, there is a reason for some implementations forcing the user to keep a backup. I‘ve already shot myself in the foot, so keeping a backup seems to be a good idea to me. Btw, I would always prefer `sed ... && mv ...` over the semicolon version to avoid overwriting my source with an empty file in case of an error.

Comment: I completely agree in that it is always a good idea to keep a backup. But that is an issue which is orthogonal to a solution being portable. There is no portable solution for **no additional file** (`-i` receiving an empty value). @Philippos

Comment: The most reliable solution, IMhO, is to make a copy of the original (`cp original backup`), do all modifications to a second file (`sed '…' original > result`), and, then, after all heavy processing has been done, do `cat result > original` and `rm result`. That way you get to keep a backup, the result file keeps the symbolic links (if any), permissions and inode number of the original. But that has the cost of (**short lived**) additional disk space. That shouldn't be an important issue in most cases. @Philippos